# Using Meteor.methods and Meteor.call

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have the following server code:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
  Meteor.publish("AllMessages", function() {
    lists._ensureIndex( { location : "2d" } );
    return lists.find();
  });
});

Meteor.methods({
  getListsWithinBounds: function(bounds) {
    lists._ensureIndex( { location : "2d" } );
    return lists.find( { "location": { "$within": { "$box": [ [bounds.bottomLeftLng, bounds.bottomLeftLat] , [bounds.topRightLng, bounds.topRightLat] ] } } } );
  }
});
```

and this client code:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
  map = L.map('map_canvas').locate({setView: true, maxZoom: 21});
  L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
  }).addTo(map);
    bounds = {};    
    map.on('locationfound', function(e){ 
      bounds.bottomLeftLat = map.getBounds()._southWest.lat;
      bounds.bottomLeftLng = map.getBounds()._southWest.lng;
      bounds.topRightLat = map.getBounds()._northEast.lat;
      bounds.topRightLng = map.getBounds()._northEast.lng;
      console.log(bounds);
      Meteor.call("getListsWithinBounds", bounds, function(err, result) {
        console.log('call'+result); // should log a LocalCursor pointing to the relevant lists
      });
    });
});
```

I get on my server logs:

```
Internal exception while processing message { msg: 'method',
  method: 'getListsWithinBounds',
  params: 
   [ { bottomLeftLat: 50.05008477838258,
       bottomLeftLng: 0.384521484375,
       topRightLat: 51.63847621195153,
       topRightLng: 8.3221435546875 } ],
  id: '2' } undefined
```

but I cant't figure out why...

Comment: Can you check your meteor terminal at the same time this happens?

Comment: The error msg on the bottom is the meteor terminal..

Comment: Have you indexed fields for a geospatial query? Meteor might hide mongodb errors

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392566/mongo-geospatial-index-and-meteor

Comment: Indeed I didn't ensureindex, I just added that, but I get a new kind of error:) Running on: http://localhost:3000/
Maximum call stack size exceeded
Exited with code: 1
Maximum call stack size exceeded
Exited with code: 1
Maximum call stack size exceeded
Exited with code: 1
Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.

Comment: Try putting `lists._ensureIndex( { location : "2d" } );` in meteor startup instead. The call stack size exceeded means theres an infinite loop somewhere on server side code

Comment: I have it in both startup and the method. I update my server side code in my question, have a look.

Comment: Could you try moving it up so its not in the publish function but in the startup? It only needs to be run once, then not after as the index will be added to your collection. I think even if you've used it in your startup once it's not needed again unless you use a fresh db

Comment: I had it there before and I had an error which I pasted originally in my question...

Comment: Can you simulate a query manually in mongodb by running `meteor mongo` and performing it over on your lists collection and see if it gives a result if you used real values?

Comment: Or could you paste what a document looks like in the lists collection?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26817/discussion-between-george-katsanos-and-akshat)

Comment: Try a the call method after map.on with and array of bound instead of calling many times.

Comment: You can also try youing the bound ={} inside the function.

Comment: Αkshat helped me find a solution so he can post it as an answer so that I'll accept it..

Answer (score 16):

You cannot return a Collection cursor - it's unable to be converted into an EJSON object. Return the results of your query as an array.

e.g.

```
return Lists.find(...).fetch();
```

Comment: Right, but that won't be a reactive data source. Maybe you'd be better off using `Meteor.publish` instead of `Meteor.methods` in this case?…